# MySQL join with match on relational table

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

I'm dealing with a MySQL DB schema that has several tables and I was wondering if it's possible to submit 1 query to get all of the data I need. The one hiccup I'm having is there is a table that references a key id to another table. For instance-

> Table1:

```
________________________
|  id   |  profession   |
+---------+-------------+
| 1     |   stockbroker |   
| 2     |   doctor      |
| ...   |   ...         |
```

Tabel2:

```
____________________________
|  id        |  rehab      |
+------------+-------------+
| 1          | meth-head   |   
| 2          | alcoholic   |
```

Tabel3:

```
__________________________
|  table1_id |  table2_id |
+------------+------------+
|      1     |      2     |
```

Is it possible to get the key_id value from Table2 if I only know Table1.key_id?

Something along the lines of -

> SELECT table2.value1 FROM Table1, Table2, Table3 WHERE (the
>   corresponding table2_id value of table1_id in Table3)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: To clarify: Do Table1 and Table2, as you've shown them, have three rows each? Do all your tables have two columns, one named "name" and the other named "value"? Given your sample data, can you provide a sample result set?

Comment: I updated the table to display the format that I think would make more sense to you (and probably the correct format).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading your question correctly it looks like `Table3` is a pivot table, so the tables 1 and 2 have a many-to-many relationship.  You would have to join from `Table1` to `Table3` then back to `Table2`.

```
SELECT t2.value1, t2.value2
FROM Table1 t1
    INNER JOIN Table3 t3 ON t1.key_id = t3.table1_id
    INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t3.table2_id = t2.key_id
WHERE t1.key_id = [your value]
```

Keep in mind this could produce many values for Table2 per one value in Table1, and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given much information but,

```
SELECT t2.value1
FROM table2 AS t2, table1 AS t1, table3 AS t3
WHERE t1.key_id = 1 
AND t1.key_id = t3.table1_id AND t3.table2_id = t2.key_id;
```

would work for that limited example.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9cf42/5